# How can I use the -last parameter in PowerShell to select files to copy?

Tags: powershell, file-io

Each day we create copies of the production databases that users then copy from the server to their local machines. I want to automate this process with a script that will select the last three files in a particular path and copy them.

I can use

```
dir $HS3BackupPath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3
```

to properly select and display the three files I want to copy, but I've been unsuccessful in piping the results of this to a copy command.

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660487/powershell-and-last-modified-date), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735890/powershell-keep-last-31-files) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589026/powershell-getting-last-log-off-date-and-time-of-a-computer), I tried

```
dir $HS3BackupPath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3 |
  copy-item $HS3BackupPath $Dest
```

and got this error:

```
copy-item : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\scripts\RefreshHS3.ps1:96 char:63
+     dir $HS3BackupPath | sort LastWriteTime |select -last 3 | copy-item $HS3Back ...
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (HS3PREcompress-...11-38-17-62.mdb:PSObject) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Trying variations, I'm here now

```
Copy-Item $HS3BackupPath $Dest | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3
```

and getting this error:

```
Copy-Item : Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item.
At C:\scripts\RefreshHS3.ps1:98 char:1
+ Copy-Item $HS3BackupPath $Dest | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\DC1\HS3_db_Backups\:String) [Copy-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyContainerItemToLeafError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Anyone know the proper syntax to copy these files appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dir $HS3BackupPath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3 | ForEach-Object{ copy-item $_.FullName $Dest}
```

The input object for `Copy-Item` is the issue. One way around it is to use a `ForEach-Object` and use the `FullName` property as the `Path` for `Copy-Item`

Like Ansgar says you can just pipe directly into `Copy-Item` as well as long as you use the named parameter `-Destination`

```
dir $HS3BackupPath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 3 | Copy-Item -Destination $Dest
```

`Copy-Item` only has space for 2 positional paramenters for `-Path` and `-Destination`. In your example those were specified leaving no space for the pipeline input. Removing the `-Path` allowed the pipeline input to match. To make sure there were no positional conflicts `-Destination` needed to be named.

Comment: Using a loop is not required, as `Copy-Item` can read from the pipeline. You just need to use `-Destination` here: `... | Copy-Item -Destination $Dest`.